# How to display all elements in an array as classes Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little big problem . I have some classes pushed in a array and I want to transform them in classes . This is my try:

```
    var currentChild;
    currentChild = $(this).index() + 1;
    var array=[];
    if(currentChild >=6){
        for ( var n = currentChild-1; n>currentChild-4; n--){
            var items= $('.dropdown.level-2').parent().parent().find('.item.nv1:nth-child(' +n+ ')').attr("class");
            array.push(items);
        } 
    }

    var totalHeight = 0;
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        totalHeight += parseInt($(array[i]).height()); // here i want to select all the classes in the array but i can't figured it out how to make it work because javascript doesn't see them as classes
    }
```

This is just a little part of my final code.

Comment: My answer had a syntax error, try `totalHeight += parseInt($('.' + array[i]).height());` again

Comment: If the answer didnt work or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.` before the `array[i]` like

```
totalHeight += parseInt($('.' + array[i]).height());
```

`.` is the class selector

As a side note, the following line may break if there are multiple classes

```
var items= $('.dropdown.level-2').parent().parent().find('.item.nv1:nth-child(' +n+ ')').attr("class");
```

Therefore, use `concat` and `split` like

```
var items= $('.dropdown.level-2').parent().parent().find('.item.nv1:nth-child(' +n+ ')').attr("class").split(' ');
array.concat(items);
```